Is it possible to upload a dataset with custom format in Vertex AI managed datasets
I'm looking for a way to upload custom jsonl format for my test-cases in GCP vertex AI managed datasets.
Here's a sample json structure that I would like to upload
{
    "category": "Diacritics",
    "description": "Diacritics influence ranking",
    "comment": null, // or string
    "model": "pl",
    "build": "12345", // or null
    "timeless": false,
    "age": { "value": 40, "unit": "years" },
    "query": "zab",
    "expected": "s_XXX"
}

I know that there is specific format required but In documentation I didn't see any metadata fields that I could use. Should I just use regular google cloud storage?
